# If a user inputs an invalid character how can I get my program to output a message to the user?

Tags: java

If the user enters the wrong character such as "E" or "A" in my program how can I output a message to the user? The line which I'm speaking about in my program is when the user has to choose to input one out of three characters P, M or D. However, if the user inputs another character which isn't listed I want the program to display a message.

As you can see if the user inputs "E" the program skips to the next step. However, I want the user to be **notified and asked again to enter the correct value which is "P, M or D"**.

In order to do what I'm trying to achieve I believe I need to do an if statement so here what I have tried.

```
if((i = P,M,D) && (i < ?)) {
   System.out.println("ERROR, please input only P,M or D.");
}
```

[Screenshot of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYOt8.png)

**JAVA CODE**

```
String grade;
int yr2cred[] = new int[18];
char yr2grade[] = new char[18];
for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter your grade for unit " + i +" "+(username) + ".");
    grade = userinput.next();
    yr2grade[i - 1] = grade.charAt(0);
    if (yr2grade[i - 1] == 'P' || yr2grade[i - 1] == 'p') {
        yr2cred[i - 1] = yr2cred[i - 1] + P;
    }
    if (yr2grade[i - 1] == 'M' || yr2grade[i - 1] == 'm') {
        yr2cred[i - 1] = yr2cred[i - 1] + M;
    }
    if (yr2grade[i - 1] == 'D' || yr2grade[i - 1] == 'd') {
        yr2cred[i - 1] = yr2cred[i - 1] + D;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using else statements?

Comment: Good idea, I didn't think about that. I know it's long but maybe I could do a statement highlighting each letter then saying what the program has to do if they enter that character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a **while** loop within the **for** loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
    while (grade.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your grade for unit " + i + " " + username + ".");
        grade = userinput.next().toLowerCase();
        yr2grade[i - 1] = grade.charAt(0);
        if (yr2grade[i - 1] == 'p') {
            yr2cred[i - 1] = yr2cred[i - 1] + P;
        } else if (yr2grade[i - 1] == 'm') {
            yr2cred[i - 1] = yr2cred[i - 1] + M;
        } else if (yr2grade[i - 1] == 'd') {
            yr2cred[i - 1] = yr2cred[i - 1] + D;
        } else {
            System.err.println("Invalid Grade Supplied! Try Again.\n");
            grade = "";
        }
    }
    grade = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible code is here. We iterate on units, for each unit we ask to enter the grade value until valid one will be entered. At the end the list of grades is printed.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int unitsCount = 18;
        String[] unitGrades = new String[unitsCount];

        String grade;

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < unitsCount; i++) {
            grade = "";
            while ( ! (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("P") || grade.equalsIgnoreCase("M") || grade.equalsIgnoreCase("D") ) ) {
                if (!"".equals(grade)){
                    System.out.println("ERROR, please input only P,M or D.");
                }
                System.out.print("Please enter your grade for unit " + i + ": ");
                grade = userInput.next();
            }
            unitGrades[i] = grade;
        }
        System.out.println("Unit grades: "+Arrays.toString(unitGrades));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking your time to do this. However,  I want the user to be notified and asked again to enter the correct value which is "P, M or D". I have added my full program code and updated the explanation to make it more clear. Once again thanks!

Comment: I've updated code to output error message when invalid grade was entered.